# How to update the view after the model has changed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

Say I have a `Logger` class, a `LoggerViewModel` class and a `MainWindow` with a `TextBox`. The `Logger` class is a thread-safe singleton, so I have only an instance of it in the application domain.

```
public sealed class Logger : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly Logger _Instance = new Logger();

    private static readonly object _SyncLock = new object();
    private static List<LogEntry> _Data = new List<LogEntry>();

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private Logger() { ; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static Logger Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entry"></param>
    public void Write(LogEntry entry)
    {
        lock (_SyncLock)
        {
            _Data.Add(entry);
        }
        this.RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("Entries");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="component"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public void Write(string component, string message)
    {
        LogEntry entry = LogEntry.Create(component, message);
        Write(entry);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public IList<LogEntry> Entries
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_SyncLock)
            {
                return new ReadOnlyCollection<LogEntry>(_Data);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    private void RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The `Logger` unique instance is updated by more thread while the application is running, so I would update the `TextBox` on the `MainWindow` whenever the model (that is the `Logger` singleton class) changes.

How to connect the Model and the ViewModel between them? I emphasize that the Model is changed by only a few application thread, so it is read-only from the point of view of UI.

I provided the `LoggerText` property within the `LoggerViewModel` class, since I thought the following working mechanism.
 **1.** When the *Model* (the `Logger` instance) changes, it notifies the *ViewModel*.
 **2.** The *ViewModel* receives the notify by the *Model* and create a new `string` containing all the messages from the logger.
 **3.** The *ViewModel* notifies the *View*.

```
public class LoggerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Logger _LoggerModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public LoggerViewModel()
    {
        _LoggerModel = Logger.Instance;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string LoggerText
    {
        get
        {
            string text = "";
            List<LogEntry> entries = new List<LogEntry>(_LoggerModel.Entries);
            foreach (LogEntry entry in entries)
            {
                text += entry.ToString();
                text += "\n";
            }
            return text;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

How the *ViewModel* can intercept the notifications sent by the *Model*?

Comment: What's wrong with the normal *Add a property of type `Logger` into your view model and data bind to the `Entries` property in the UI* approach? If the `static` class is causing you problems, then just add the property into a normal class and just use your Singleton class to update the normal class.

Comment: I added the code sample of the `LoggerViewModel` class. I would bind the `LoggerText` property in the UI when the model changes.

Comment: With WPF (and most programming languages really), you will benefit from separating your data from your data access code. Your best bet is to use a plain collection property (the data) and to populate it using an external class accessed from the view model.

Comment: @Sheridan: Could you please tell me an example?

Comment: `How the ViewModel can intercept the notifications sent by the Model?` - Add a `PropertyChanged` handler in your VM. So in the ctor of your VM where you have `_LoggerModel = Logger.Instance;` add in the following line `_LoggerModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.PropertyName);`. Now when your Model's "Entries" property changes via the `Write` method, this handler will get invoked in your VM. Right now it will print `Entries` to the output window, you can change that to `_LoggerModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("LoggerText");`

Comment: What? An example of making a collection property?? Or an example of setting that property using an external class??? You should be able to do both already.

Comment: ..contd, That should get your UI updated accordingly. Just call the RaisePropertyChanged after checking the args to be for Entries, else you'll refresh the UI for `LoggerText` for any INPC changes from the model. Do remember you need to remove the INPC handler you've added in the VM when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I do not like that you are using a singleton.  When using the singleton pattern you are making it hard on yourself when testing or reusing your view controllers.  I would instead inject the `Logger` dependency into your `LoggerViewModel` class.

Aside from that one way to solve your problem is to register a handler for the `PropertyChanged` event on your `Logger` and build the text when the event fires for the `Entries` property.

In `LoggerViewModel` you would then add a property handler and update the `LoggerText` property as needed.

```
public LoggerViewModel(Logger loggerModel /* Dependency injection*/)
{
    _LoggerModel = loggerModel;
    _LoggerModel.PropertyChanged += this.LoggerModel_PropertyChanged;
}

private void LoggerModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.PropertyName == "Entries")
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();  // Use StringBuilder for performance
        List<LogEntry> entries = new List<LogEntry>(_LoggerModel.Entries);
        foreach (LogEntry entry in entries)
        {
            text.AppendLine(entry.ToString());
        }
        this.LoggerText = text.ToString();            
    }
}

private string _loggerText;
public string LoggerText
{
    set
    {
       _loggerText = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("LoggerText");
    }

    get
    {
        return _loggerText;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: The above code is written without a compiler.

Comment: Great! Thanks to your code sample, now the ViewModel is correctly updated whenever the Model changes.